# Freeze First Column of Sharepoint online List view using Jquery/javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery, css

i want to fix first column (ex: Title column) of my sharepoint list view, so  that whenever the user scroll horizontally the first column should be fixed.
[image]

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: No.. in this post user suggest a work around, but i am looking for a piece of code to achieve the above requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position` CSS property with [sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) value (doesn't work with IE). You would iterate over the `table` HTML rows to update row style.

However, since it's a table, you need to know which cell refers to the field to *freeze*. To do so, we will retrieve all our fields index (cells position):

```
var tableFieldsIndex = new Object; // Contains [fieldName] = index
var viewFields = ctx.ListSchema.Field; // All fields
viewFields.forEach(function(field, index) {
    tableFieldsIndex[field.Name] = parseInt(index);
});
```

Now let us iterate over all the rows being displayed and *freeze* every second cell:

```
var tableRows = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-listviewtable')[0].rows;
[].forEach.call(tableRows, function(tr) {
    var cells = tr.getElementsByClassName('ms-cellstyle');
    cells[1].style.position = 'sticky'; // Freezing cell 2
    cells[1].style.left = (5+(i*90)) +'px';
});
```

What may be even more interesting now is to define some function that would *freeze* specified fields.

```
function freezeColumns(fields) { // An array of fields name (strings)
    if(!fields || !ctx)
        return false;

    // Fields index (cells)
    var tableFieldsIndex = new Object;
    var viewFields = ctx.ListSchema.Field;
    viewFields.forEach(function(field, index) {
        tableFieldsIndex[field.Name] = parseInt(index);
    });

    // Iterate over displayed rows
    var table = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-listviewtable');
    var tableRows = table && table[0].rows ? (ctx.inGridMode ? table[1].rows : table[0].rows) : []; // Deal with edit mode
    [].forEach.call(tableRows, function(tr) {
        var cells = tr.getElementsByClassName('ms-cellstyle');
        for(var i=0;i<fields.length;i++) {
            var cellIndex = tableFieldsIndex[fields[i]];
            if(cells[cellIndex]) { // Be sure given field is actually displayed
                cells[cellIndex].style.position = 'sticky';
                cells[cellIndex].style.left = (5+(i*90)) +'px'; // Add an offset to make sure sticky fields won't overlap
                cells[cellIndex].style.backgroundColor = ctx.inGridMode ? 'white' : 'inherit';
            }
        }
    });

}
```